# Call a command line from python to execute a program in batch mode with args

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, segger-jlink

I need to call a program in command line that will be executed in batch mode. This program receives a file with extension .jlink that contains a series of commands that the program JLink.exe will execute and then close.

I tried to execute in the following way:

```
os.system('C:/SEGGER/JLink_V490d/JLink.exe -CommanderScript D:\Files\CommandFile.jlink')
```

But this command executes the program in normal mode, not accepting the arguments.

How can I call as execution of command line and then send that command so the program executes in batch mode with those arguments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892355/passing-arguments-into-os-system

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820420/python-share-the-command-line-argument-to-os-system-call

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.call(["C:\SEGGER\JLink_V490d\JLink.exe", 
                 "-CommanderScript", "D:\Files\CommandFile.jlink"])
```

You can also use `shell=True` to just execute a command directly in a shell (what you were trying to do with `os.system`), but this is not recommended because it's a security hazard.

More info here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html